# plot histogram for many columns quickly using groupby function of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like
[image]
Here one of column is named **label**, that can take only two possible values 0 or 1.

I would like to make histogram for label 1 and for label 0 separately one top of other, like

[image]

I am able to make this for one of the column (named "MA_CL05") like:

```
temp = infile.groupby('label')
for k, v in temp:
  if k == 1:
    v.MA_CL05.hist(label='1',figsize=(15,15),bins=25,alpha=1.0,histtype = 'step',lw=4)
  if k == 0:
    v.MA_CL05.hist(label='0',figsize=(15,15),bins=25,alpha=1.0,histtype = 'step',lw=4)
plt.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 51})
plt.show()
```

I can copy and past this patch for all of 20 columns and it will be fine. But, is there any easy way to plot this histogram of type ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAuvo.png)) in one go?

Comment: Do you want all the histograms in one plot?

Comment: nope.... I want separate histogram for each attribute. But, in dataframe there are two labels 0 and 1. So, for each attribute, we have two histogram one for 0 and another for 1. I want these two histograms in one plot.

Comment: So you want 20 different plots?

Comment: yes... 20 different plots.

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47089306/5864582). I guess it's quite the same.

Comment: was that helpful @ramkrishna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another loop, looping about the columns of the dataframe and specifying the axes to plot to.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,5)

for col,ax in zip(infile.columns[2:],axes.flatten()):
    temp = infile.groupby('label')
    for k, v in temp:
        v[col].hist(label=str(k),bins=25,alpha=1.0,histtype = 'step',lw=4, ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 51})
plt.show()
```